Proove compact convergence on G
I have proven an Exercise, but i am not sure at one point. Here it goes:

let $f_n(z)$ be a sequence of holomophic functions on a Region $G$
$f_n$ converges at a point $z_0 \in G$
let $f_n^\prime$ be compact convergent on $G$

Proove that $f_n$ is compact convergent on $G$
The first step is to proove that $f_n$ is locally bounded in $G$ (here, i am not sure):
If there exists $a \in G$ with $n \rightarrow \infty : f_n(a) = \infty$, there must be a $|z_0| \leq |b| \leq |a|$ in $G$ so that $n \rightarrow \infty :f_n^\prime(b) = \infty$, Contradiction.
Now, we use Montels theorem to proove pointwise convergence:
If there exists $c \in G$ where $f_n(c)$ is not convergent, after Montel, there exist 2 subsequences $g_n$ and $h_n$ with $g_n(c) \neq h_n(c)$. 
But because $f_n^\prime$ is compact convergent, it follows that $n \rightarrow \infty : (g_n - h_n)^{(k)} = 0 \forall k \gt 0$. Because both functions are holomorphic, we view them as power-series which differ at most on a constant term. This again cannot be the case, because $n \rightarrow \infty : g_n(z_0) = h_n(z_0)$.
On Regions with holomorphic functions, pointwise convergence implies compact convergence.
qed.
I am not sure if the reasoning behind the local boundedness is rigorous enough (i dont think so); if there is a theorem from real analysis that helps here, i would be glad to know it. thx in advance

I think you can just see these functions as real functions and their partial derivatives compact converge. Then uniform convergence of derivatives and pointwise convergence at a point will give uniform convergence of the series.
